# Email subscription to a given question answers *and* comments?

Tags: support, comments, answers, notifications, email

I could not find a solid documentation to this question.

Is there a way to subscribe by *email* to a given question's answers *and* comments?

For example, this is a question which I answered:

[Need assistance making a batch file for renaming files in separate folders](https://superuser.com/questions/358386/need-assistance-making-a-batch-file-for-renaming-files-in-separate-folders)

People are adding comments to my answer.

Is there a way to get email notifications about new comments so I can read and relate to them quickly?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to deliver the notifications you get in your global inbox: see the [Improved Global Email Notifications](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) blog entry.

You have the option to get those emails sent weekly, daily, or every three hours (or not at all).

I don't think immediate notification by email is possible, and judging by the status of the various related questions, it's not likely to be implemented. See for example Jeff's answer to this question: [Daily mail notification should include comments on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76709/daily-mail-notification-should-include-comments-on-questions)

Comment: Mat, I read your answer and reference, but I steel don't understand why not allow users, within every individual post, to subscribe to answers and, if the wish, also subscribe to comments.

It should be each individual own choice. But maybe I don't understand this platform well enough.

Comment: See this answer for more about why it is probably not going to get implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions/31596#31596

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, what you ask is not supported and won't be as long as Jeff is active around here.

What you do have is RSS feed for every question e.g. [for this very question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/112970) - you got link in the bottom right corner of the question, below the "Related" section.

I beleive that some RSS clients/readers are smart enough to notify only when something in the feed change, so this is way around to achieve what you want.

Edit: from second glance, looks like the feed does not contain comments.. sorry!